# How to use "Find My Phone" beeping feature (not location sharing) with a different Apple ID

Tags: apple-id, find-my-iphone

My girlfriend and I both have iDevices. We each have our own Apple ID. Every once in a while one of us misplaces a device... you know the drill, "Honey, could you call my phone for me?" And then it turns out it's on vibrate so we can't hear it, or it's my iPad we're looking for, and we have to go to a computer and log in with that person's account, to trigger the "Find my phone" sound.

We'd much rather be able to do that from our mobile devices. Is this possible? I know that I can use "Find my Friends" to see the location of a device on a different account, but what I need is the "ring at full volume" feature of "Find my phone." Is there any way to do that from another device? Also, can it be done from an Android device? (The iCloud website doesn't allow android devices to log in.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from Find My iPhone on another iPhone, you just need to sign in as the person whose phone you're trying to find [or get them to do it].

Alternatively, you can find all members' phones if you use [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060).

I doubt there's any way to do it from an Android. That really wouldn't be considered safe.